# Create JSON object with Swift Xcode

Tags: json, swift, xcode, object, swiftui

I have a JSON object below that uses everything from Strings, Bools and Int's.  I'm currently having a difficult time recreating the `person_details` section of the object and I think because it's in brackets and has multiple values, like `[String: Bool]`, `[String: String]` & `[String: Int]` ?

I posted towards the bottom what populates on the console, but any help structuring there person_details section in the would be great.
You'll see below, in my let order, I'm structuring the data.

```
let testJson = """
{
"household": {
    "region": "PA",
    "household_size": 1,
    "receiving_benefits": [
    ],
    "energy_crisis": false,
    "utility_providers": [
        "peco"
    ],
    "residence_type": "other",
    "property_tax_past_due": false,
    "home_needs_repairs": false,
    "filed_previous_year_tax_return": false,
    "heating_system_needs_repairs": false,
    "at_risk_of_homelessness": false,
    "received_maximum_benefit": {
        "cip": false
    },
    "person_details": [
        {
            "age": 18,
            "marital_status": "single",
            "minimum_employment_over_extended_period": false,
            "work_status": "recent_loss",
            "pregnant": false,
            "attending_school": false,
            "disabled": false
        }
    ],
    "incomes": [
        {
            "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
            "countable_group": "household",
            "year": "current"
        },
        {
            "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
            "countable_group": "household",
            "year": "previous"
        }
    ],
    "assets": [
        {
            "amount": 1000,
            "countable_group": "household"
        }
    ]
}
}
"""

struct Eligibility: Encodable {
    let residence: String
    let hhmembers: Int
    let receivingBen: [String]
    let unhoused: Bool
    let utilityType: [String]
    let residenceType: String
    let propertyTax: Bool
    let homeRepairs: Bool
    let fileLastTax: Bool
    let heatRepairs: Bool
    let receivingMax: [String: Bool]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case residence = "region"
        case hhmembers = "household_size"
        case receivingBen = "receiving_benefits"
        case unhoused = "at_risk_of_homelessness"
        case utilityType = "utility_providers"
        case residenceType = "residence_type"
        case propertyTax = "property_tax_past_due"
        case homeRepairs = "home_needs_repairs"
        case fileLastTax = "filed_previous_year_tax_return"
        case heatRepairs = "heating_system_needs_repairs"
        case receivingMax = "received_maximum_benefit"
    }
}

struct PersonDetails: Encodable {
            let age: Int
           //  let marital_status: String
            // let minimum_employment_over_extended_period: Bool
            // let work_status: String
           //  let pregnant: Bool
            // let attending_school: Bool
           //  let disabled: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case age = "age"
      //  case marital_status = "marital_status"
      //  case minimum_employment_over_extended_period = "minimum_employment_over_extended_period"
      //  case work_status = "work_status"
      //  case pregnant = "pregnant"
      //  case attending_school = "attending_school"
      //  case disabled = "disabled"
    }
}
```

I believe What I'm missing is inside the `let order =` , see below:

```
struct Order: Encodable {
    let household: Eligibility
    let person_details: PersonDetails
}
 
let order = Order(household: Eligibility(residence: "PA", hhmembers: 1, receivingBen: [], unhoused: false, utilityType: ["Peco"], residenceType: "other", propertyTax: false, homeRepairs: false, fileLastTax: false, heatRepairs: false, receivingMax: ["cip": false]), person_details: PersonDetails(age: 19))



let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

let orderJsonData = try! encoder.encode(order)

print(String(data: orderJsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

Inside the Console shows that person_details in outside of 'household' but I would need the person_details inside of the household object as the above full JSON object shows at the top of the question (note square brackets too).  Console below:

```
{
  "household" : {
    "region" : "PA",
    "residence_type" : "other",
    "at_risk_of_homelessness" : false,
    "property_tax_past_due" : false,
    "utility_providers" : [
      "Peco"
    ],
    "home_needs_repairs" : false,
    "filed_previous_year_tax_return" : false,
    "household_size" : 1,
    "receiving_benefits" : [

    ],
    "heating_system_needs_repairs" : false,
    "received_maximum_benefit" : {
      "cip" : false
    }
  },
  "person_details" : {
    "age" : 19
  }
}
```

Comment: The quick way to get your swift structs and your json data to match, is to copy and paste your json data into https://quicktype.io/ and use the swift structs generated in your code.

Comment: Agree it's the quick and easy way, but it doesn't help with understanding.  I always think, especially when new to it, that it's better to do it manually as that way when you hit problems with the data you'll understand it better.

Comment: Yes, I agree @flanker.  Thank you workingdog, I'll keep this site in my arsenal.  If there are any ways to help with my problem, just putting the 'person_details' array inside the household object, that would be golden.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the structure of your data hierarchy wrong converting from JSON to swift.

It should be...

```
struct Order: Codable {
   let household: Household
}

struct Household: Codable {
   let personDetails: [Person]
}

struct Person: Codable {
   let age: Int
   let maritalStatus: String
   let minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod: Bool
   let workStatus: String
   let pregnant: Bool
   let attendingSchool: Bool
   let disabled: Bool
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let order = try! decoder.decode(Order.self, from: Data(testJson.utf8))
```

returns

> Person(age: 18, maritalStatus: "single",
> minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod: false, workStatus: "recent_loss",
> pregnant: false, attendingSchool: false, disabled: false)]

Also worth pointing out is the use of the `.keyDecodingStrategy` to ease the converting from snake case.  This saves defining the `CodingKeys`.  Obviously this will only work where you're happy to keep the naming the same.

Comment: Thanks @flanker, question: I'm getting an error 'Cannot find 'testJson' in scope'.  Can you tell me what testJson is ?  I first thought it was the name of the swift file itself then I changed to my file's name and got the same error.  Any idea?  Thanks!

Comment: It's the json string you provided in your post :-)

Comment: Hey @flanker, I can obviously print(order) but is there a way I can pretty-print in the console rather it being a long string?  Thanks!

Comment: You could add a method to whichever struct you wanted to show in the console that prints it out.  A better option would be to conform the struct you want to output to `CustomStringConvertible` and use that so its `.description` is formatted as you want.